# EF6 MVC5 C# - Como manter filtros com páginação via QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Boa tarde,

Tenho várias páginas por onde o usuário pode filtrar por 5 campos distintos e quando o usuário clica no botão pesquisar do formulário, que está configurado com o método GET, a pesquisa é passada na URL como QueryString, uma variavel para cada campo.

O problema ocorre quando preciso criar a páginação desta tela, pois quando tento mudar de página, também passando pela URL, os dados da pesquisa são perdidos.

Sei que se eu colocar cada variavel no ActionLink da paginação, vou conseguir obter cada uma das variáveis, mantendo a pesquisa e a paginação. O problema é que minha paginação está sendo montada em uma Partial View genérica (abaixo o código) e gostaria de continuar assim, sem precisar criar uma páginação distinta para cada tela. É possível?

```
<div>
    Página @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
    de @Model.PageCount
    @if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("<< Primeira", "Details", null, new { pagina = 1 }, null)
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @Html.ActionLink("< Anterior", "Details", null, new { pagina = Model.PageNumber - 1 }, null)
    }
    else
    {
        @: [ Você está na primeira página ]
    }

    @if (Model.HasNextPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Próxima >", "Details", null, new { pagina = Model.PageNumber + 1 }, null)
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @Html.ActionLink("Última >>", "Details", null, new { pagina = Model.PageCount }, null)
    }
    else
    {
        @: [ Você está na última página ]
    }
</div>
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acredito que o seu filtro permita parginação e ordenação, então uma saida é adicionar os dois no seu modelo.

por exemplo, um crud basico com filtro pelo titulo e range de data.:

```
public class EntityModel
{
    public EntityFilter Filtro { get; set; }
    public List<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
}

public class EntityFilter : BaseFilter
{
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataInicial { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataFinal { get; set; }
}

public class BaseFilter
{
    public int PaginaAtual { get; set; }
    public int PaginaTamanho { get; set; }
    public string Coluna { get; set; }
    public bool Ascendente { get; set; }
}
```

o seu form, pode ser algo como.:

```
@model EntityModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Filter.PaginaAtual)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Filter.PaginaTamanho)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Filter.Coluna)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Filter.Ascendente)
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Filter.Titulo);
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Filter.Titulo);
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Filter.DataInicial);
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Filter.DataInicial);
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Filter.DataFinal);
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Filter.DataFinal);
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
    </div>
}
```

já o seu botão de paginação, basicamente terá de setar o `input[type='hidden'][name='Filter.PaginaAtual']` e forçar o envio do formulário.

```
(function () {
    var form = document.querySelector("form");
    var paginaAtual = document.querySelector("input[type='Filter.PaginaAtual']");
    var paginacao = document.querySelectorAll(".paginacao");

    var onPaginaClick = function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        paginaAtual.value = evt.target.value;

        var evento = new new Event('submit', { 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': true });
        form.dispatchEvent(evento);
    };

    [].forEach.call(paginacao, function (pagina, indice) {
        pagina.addEventListener("click", onPaginaClick);
    })
})();
```

E claro, você terá de adicionar uma logica semelhante no `JS` para persistir o tamanho da pagina, coluna para ordenar e se a ordem é ascendente ou não.